# sublime anaconda can't autocomplete on dot

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I follow the document:
http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/IDE/#toc_3

Create a file which name Python.sublime-settings in the Packages/User 
and add following

```
{
     "auto_complete_triggers": [{"selector": "source.python - string - comment - constant.numeric", "characters": "."}]
}
```

but it won't effect, what's wrong with it. thank you very much

Comment: Are you sure you got the path to the file correct? You can double check by selecting `Preferences > Settings - Syntax Specific` while you're editing a Python file. Also, does the Sublime console display any errors or messages?

Comment: e, sorry. what path i need to set? And how should i do? i check the Syntax Specific . it's none in the JSON.sublime-settings

Comment: If you select that menu item while you're editing a Python file, it will open the Python specific settings, which is the file you are supposed to create. If you see the text above, you put the file in the right place and there is some other issue. If you don't see that text, then you created the file in the wrong place, to add it to the file that this command opens.